# improper url link in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am working in MEAN stack. For my front-end, I am trying to render data of single item from my item list with angular. When I click the item, the URL changes to other than I have set and I don't get the data. I was able to see this only after using debugging mode. The expected link is `/item/:itemid` but I am getting `/item/partials/item.html` I have used the following files:

**main.route.js** (only route with problem shown)

```
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/item/:itemid', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/item.html',
        controller: 'productCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    }); 
};
```

**myData.service.js**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('myData', myData);

function myData ($http) {
    var itemById = function (itemid) {
        return $http.get('/api/items/' + itemid);
    };

    return {
        itemById : itemById
    };
}
```

**product.controller.js**

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('productCtrl', productCtrl)

function productCtrl($routeParams, myData) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.itemid = $routeParams.itemid;

    myData.itemById(vm.itemid)
        .success(function(data) {
            vm.data = { item : data };
            vm.pageHeader = {
                title: vm.data.item.name
            };
        })
        .error(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
};
```

**items.html** (link to single item page)

```
<a href='/#/item/{{ item._id }}'>{{ item.name }}</a>
```

**item.html**

```
<div  ng-controller='productCtrl'>
    <div class='container'>
        <page-header content='vm.pageHeader.title'></page-header>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Forgive me if the question doesn't make much sense as I am new to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is exactly why Angular recommends you set a `<base>` when using HTML5 mode. Your `templateUrl` is being loaded relative to the current URL path which is `/item`

Comment: Also, don't use `ng-controller` with routing. You're already setting the controller in the route configuration

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash on this anchor below:

```js
<a href='#/item/{{ item._id }}'>{{ item.name }}</a>
```

Comment: Without that slash, the link doesn't make sense since I'm going for SPA.

Comment: Only the first slash i meant, not all slashes

Comment: if I remove the first slash the url becomes `http://localhost:3000/items#%2Fitem%2F57e860e5527a3a04e80dec80`